# Delegating constructors and templates

Tags: c++, templates, delegates, copy-constructor

Why do not delegating constructors work in the case of templates? Copy constructor does not call constant copy constructor in case of `T=U`, although without this `template <typename U>` and `<U>`'s it works.

```
template <typename T>
struct Class {
    Class () {
        std::cout << "Default constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    template <typename U>
    Class (const Class<U>& rhs) {
        std::cout << "Const copy constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    template <typename U>
    Class (Class<U>& rhs)
        : Class (const_cast<const Class<U>&> (rhs))
    {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor (templated)" << std::endl;
    }
/* // DOES NOT WORK WITHOUT THE NEXT:
    Class (Class& rhs)
        : Class (const_cast<const Class&> (rhs))
    {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor (not templated)" << std::endl;
    }
*/
};
```

Comment: [Works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18c2a8ffd206f55f)

Comment: @AntonSavin, yes, but not with T=U.

Comment: @DieterLücking, even without `template <typename U>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please notice: A template constructor is never(!) a copy constructor.
A default copy constructor will be generated, instead (if possible).

```
struct NoCopy
{
    NoCopy() {}
    NoCopy(const NoCopy&) = delete;
};

template <typename T>
struct Test
{
    NoCopy member;
    Test() {};

    template <typename U>
    Test(const Test<U>&)
    {}
};

int main()
{
    Test<int> a;
    // The following error shows the missing generation of a default constructor,
    // due to the non copyable member. Without that member, the code compiles.
    // error: use of deleted function ‘Test<int>::Test(const Test<int>&)’
    Test<int> b(a);
}
```